# Hiding Mouse Pointer on window Screen using GDI in c++

Tags: c++, c, gdi+, gdi, windows

How to hide the mouse pointer on the window screen of GDI, kindly give me some hints.

Comment: Wrong spelling, change to "Hiding".

Comment: Sorry Viet for my week english..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ShowCursor(false);`

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648396.aspx

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2004-08/0045.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GetCursorPos` to determine the location of the cursor and then if the cursor is above your GDI area you can call `ShowCursor(FALSE)`.

As soon as the cursor leaves your GDI area call `ShowCursor(TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowCursor(FALSE)`